# Проблема с определением пустых строк

Tags: java, строки

Необходимо считать данные с файла при помощи BufferedReader, выделить из исходных данных массив чисел и произвести bucket sort. Проблема с выделением пустых строк. Код:

```
public class new_1 {
    public static ArrayList<Double> bucketSort (ArrayList<Double> v, double minVal, double maxVal) {
        if ((v.size() <= 1) || (minVal == maxVal)) return v;
        else {
        ArrayList<Double> fb = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> sb = new ArrayList<Double>();
        double mid = (minVal+maxVal)/2;
        double minVal2 = Double.MAX_VALUE, maxVal2 = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            Double cur = v.get(i);
            if (cur <= mid) {
                fb.add(cur);
                if (cur >= maxVal2) maxVal2 = cur;
                }
        else {
            sb.add(cur);
            if (cur <= minVal2) minVal2 = cur;
            }
        }
        fb = bucketSort(fb, minVal, maxVal2);
        sb = bucketSort(sb, minVal2, maxVal);
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.size(); i++) {
            fb.add(sb.get(i));
        }
        return fb;
        }
    }

    public static void printResults(ArrayList<Double> a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(a.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str[] = new String[49];
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/123"));
            String all = "";
            ArrayList<String> allLines = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (true) {
                allLines.add(br.readLine());
            }
            for (int i=0; i<allLines.size(); i++) {
                all = all + allLines.get(i);
            }
            if (all == "0")  {
                System.out.println("File doesn`t have arguments. Please write some arguments in /home/s225030/123");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            str = all.split(" ");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        if (str.length < 49) {
            System.out.println("File consist of less than 49 arguments. Please write 49 or more arguments");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        if (str.length > 49){
            System.out.println("File consist of more than 49 arguments. For arguments I get last 49 arguments");
        }
        ArrayList<Double> iscom = new ArrayList<Double>();
        double[] pereh = new double[49];
        for (int i=0; i < 49; i++){
            iscom.add(0.0);
            try {
                pereh[i] = Double.parseDouble(str[i]);
                iscom.set(i, pereh[i]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong arguments");
                System.exit(3);
            }
        }
    double minVal = Double.MAX_VALUE, maxVal = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
        double cur = iscom.get(i);
        if (cur < minVal) minVal = cur;
        if (cur > maxVal) maxVal = cur;
    }
    iscom = bucketSort(iscom, minVal, maxVal);
    printResults(iscom); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Классы в яве принято именовать с большой буквы и в верблюжьем стиле.

Comment: Спасибо, я учту это